onDidCommit event not being triggered after a commit
I am currently working on a vscode extension and I am trying to update some information after a commit is made. I opted to use git's api as the ondidcommit event is just what I need. However the event is not being triggered like ondidchange state.
const gitExtension = vscode.extensions.getExtension<GitExtension>('vscode.git')?.exports;
const git = gitExtension?.getAPI(1);


if (gitExtension) {
    if (gitExtension.enabled == true) {
        git?.onDidChangeState((e: any) => {
            if (git.state == "initialized") {
            console.log("initialized")
            git.repositories[0].onDidCommit((e: any) => {
            console.log("committed")
            })
            }
        })
    }

}



I defined the event globally but this would cause issues with vscode:

Activating extension 'undefined_publisher.level' failed: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onDidCommit').

I tried to delay the events launch by using setInterval as I assumed the event was being set before the api was initialized but similar to the first block of code nothing happened.
Above I verified that the api was enabled and initialized. Doing so allows me to use other normal features of the api like identifying the uri of my repository.
